# Content From Other Pages Showing Up At The Top of My Web Page

Tags: php, apache

I currently have a LAMP stack (Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP) setup through Amazon Lightsail and have built a robust web app for internal use at my company. I'm having this weird issue where sometimes content that is supposed to be on a specific page(Page "A" for example) will show up at the top of the other pages (Pages "B", "C", and "D" for example).

Screenshot of what I'm referring to:
[Content from Page "A" on Page "B"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUCAk.png)

If I choose to "inspect" the code, I can see the code at the top of the page.
[Screenshot of inspected code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICjRa.png)

However, if I view the source code, the code from Page "A" is not there. The first lines of code are for the navbar (which is should be).
[Screenshot of page source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAXa4.png)

The fact that it's not in the source code makes me think that there is a bug in my jQuery. However...

- I don't have the same jQuery code on every page (Pages "B", "C", and "D"), but the same content from Page "A" will show up at the top of all the other pages
- Content from Page "A" only sometimes shows up on (Pages "B", "C", and "D"), not all the time.
- It's not always Page "A" that will show up at the top. Sometimes content from Page "B" will show up at the top of all the other pages (Pages "A", "C", and "D").

I know it's probably hard to help me without seeing everything, but any idea where I could go to start debugging? Is the issue with my code? Is the issue with the web server itself? Any thoughts?